# Reactjs create a provider component that pass Redux to its children

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i was wondering if its possible to create  a parent wrapper for children that would automaticly pass a part of redux store to its children.

Example

```
<ReducProvider src="user">

  <ul> {this.props.data.map(f=><li>{f.name}</li>)} </ul>

</ReducProvider>
```

here i want this ul to be rendered with props.data = the data that ReduxProvider passed it to.

i know i can simply get the part i need using connect like so

```
connect( (state,prop)=>({data:state[prop.src]}) )(ReduxProvider)
```

but sometimes i dont want the parent to listen to store changes, neither do i want the child to know where this data is coming from, so i was planning to create a Provider for every Reducer i have. this way when ever the store mutates, these providers are the only one who gona get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an answer to your question, this might solve your issue.

You can create meaningless proxy components. These components render the actual components and pass the right variables as props. I recall having read that you can generate such components automatically.

Example of such a component in ES6:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import User from './User';

class AuthenticatedUser extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <User user={this.props.user} />
    }
}

export default connect(
    (state) => ({ user: state.Authentication.user }),
    (dispatch) => {}
)(AuthenticatedUser);
```

*! code is untested*
So this code would inject the authenticated user from the state into the `User` component. Keeping the `User` component clean, i.e. you can render any user you like from any source. While you also created the option to render a connected version of the user which is automatically linked to the store.

**answer to actual question:**
I would recommend against this since the context is a bad practice through and through. But you could store your variables in the context. Children can then access these variables when requested using `contextTypes` property.

Comment: @Marrten what are meaningless proxy components. ? can you provide an example or a link ?

Comment: What I meant is: a component which does nothing by itself but render the actual component and connect to the store. Being able to inject the needed variables. They're not very useful by themselves but help you separate your Redux logic from your own business logic. I'll hit you up with an example later.

Comment: @Zalaboza: I added an example for you. Hope this clears it up for you.